# Doing multiple things with lambda expressions in one line

Tags: lambda

This is purely to simplify the code and make it more readable.

I print out a list of Windows Services on my computer. In doing so, I call the `ServiceController.GetServices()` and retrieve an array of the services. But I would prefer to get it in a strongly typed list and print it out to my txbMain text box. I have managed to both of these things in 3 lines of code. But is there a way to print out to txbMain in the first line so I can avoid the foreach loop?

```
List<ServiceController> list = ServiceController.GetServices()
    .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName)
    .ToList();

foreach (ServiceController sc in list)
    txbMain.Text += sc.DisplayName + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use your list after this statement, you can do :

```
ServiceController.GetServices()
    .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => txbMain.Text += x.DisplayName + Environment.NewLine);
```

Note that it will internally perform a foreach loop anyway.

Worse, it will first have to create a list before using the ForEach method, which is time consuming.

See [Eric Lippert's post about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Maybe you should stick with your foreach loop.

Comment: There isn't any ForEach method.

Comment: Yes there is, after the ToList() method (which I forgot at first). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes. I figured that out:-) Thanks.